# Unknown errors for "undeclared"

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

this was working earlier but now it is not because it does not recognize the settings in the first .m file below. I did #import Setting.h but it still does not work. Please help!

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EditNameViewController.h"



@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <EditNameDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIButton *froshsched;
IBOutlet UIButton *uppersched;


}
```

.m file. it says settings and 'settings are undeclared

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "Settings.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", @"Settings");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spanner"];        
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

-(IBAction)froshsched{
Settings *settings = [Settings sharedInstance];
settings.timelabelfirst = @"12:35";
settings.timelabelsecond = @"1:25";
[[Settings sharedInstance] save];
}
-(IBAction)uppersched{
Settings *settings = [Settings sharedInstance];
settings.timelabelfirst = @"12:10";
settings.timelabelsecond = @"1:00";
[[Settings sharedInstance] save];
}

-(IBAction)editclass{
EditNameViewController*vc2 = [[EditNameViewController alloc] init];
vc2.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}

-(void)dismiss{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end


-(IBAction)editclass;
-(IBAction)froshsched;
-(IBAction)uppersched;
```

here is the Settings.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Settings : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *redClassName, *orangeClassName, *yellowClassName,   *greenClassName, *ltblueClassName, *dkblueClassName, *purpleClassName, *pinkClassName,    *timelabelfirst, *timelabelsecond;

+(Settings*)sharedInstance;
-(void)save;

@end
```

and lastly here is the Settings.m file, I feel like I am missing something simple, thanks

```
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation Settings

@synthesize redClassName, orangeClassName, yellowClassName, greenClassName, ltblueClassName,  dkblueClassName, purpleClassName, pinkClassName, timelabelfirst, timelabelsecond;

-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    redClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kredClass"];
    orangeClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"korangeClass"];
    yellowClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kyellowClass"];
    greenClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kgreenClass"];
    ltblueClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kltblueClass"];
    dkblueClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kdkblueClass"];
    purpleClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kpurpleClass"];
    pinkClassName = [defaults objectForKey:@"kpinkClass"];
    timelabelfirst = [defaults objectForKey:@"ktime1"];
    timelabelsecond = [defaults objectForKey:@"ktime2"];
}
return self;
}

+(Settings*)sharedInstance{
static Settings *sharedSettings;
if(!sharedSettings) sharedSettings = [[Settings alloc] init];
return sharedSettings;
}
-(void)save{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:redClassName forKey:@"kredClass"];
[defaults setObject:orangeClassName forKey:@"korangeClass"];
[defaults setObject:yellowClassName forKey:@"kyellowClass"];
[defaults setObject:greenClassName forKey:@"kgreenClass"];
[defaults setObject:ltblueClassName forKey:@"kltblueClass"];
[defaults setObject:dkblueClassName forKey:@"kdkblueClass"];
[defaults setObject:purpleClassName forKey:@"kpurpleClass"];
[defaults setObject:pinkClassName forKey:@"kpinkClass"];
[defaults setObject:timelabelfirst forKey:@"ktime1"];
[defaults setObject:timelabelsecond forKey:@"ktime2"];
[defaults synchronize];
}

@end
```

Comment: i am sure its not complicated, i just wanted to provide as much info as possible, this is the very last thing i need help with,

Comment: Please paste the full error message.

Comment: i figured it our, I accidentally deleted @end, stupid mistake but hard to catch because it resulted in 21 errors all over the place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give us EditNameController (with its delegate). In any case I copied and pasted all of your code above and by commenting out EditNameController related items it all compiled fine (except of course these lines floating at the bottom of your file:

```
-(IBAction)editclass;
-(IBAction)froshsched;
-(IBAction)uppersched;
```

You also didnt show a "@end" at the bottom of SettingsViewController.h (which I added before compiling).